# Delete a dynamically-allocated class instance in C++?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

In C++, I have a class A, and a second class B which contains an allocated array of A. What is the correct syntax for deleting an instance of A from B?

```
class A
{
  ~A() {/*delete members of A which were dynamically allocated*/}
  //...members...
};

class B
{
  A *arrayOfA; // allocated by arrayOfA=new A[123];
};
```

This is what I have tried, to delete the i-th instance of A:

```
// Code to delete an instance of A from B:
// delete arrayofA[i]; // gives a compilation error, because delete requires a pointer
delete &arrayofA[i]; // compiles, but gives a runtime error
```

The destructor of A is being called, and seems to operate correctly. The error occurs in validation of the memory block for A (this is a debug build). Probably the error is caused by overwriting the heap allocation, but I would like to be sure the C++ syntax is correct for what I am trying to do.

64-bit Windows 7; Visual Studio 2017 v15.3.5

Comment: Could be the rule of 3 / 5 / 0.

Comment: `delete &arrayofA[i];` looks very suspicious. Didn't you want `delete [] arrayofA;` instead? Not only are you using the wrong form of delete but what is `i` here? You can't delete part of an array so it does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Why not use vectors? Or shared pointers?

Comment: Don't use raw pointers at all. Rather stick to the [***Dynamic memory management***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) facilities.

Comment: The correct way is `std::vector<A> arrayOfA;`

Comment: I really do want to delete part of the array. I assumed that `new A[123]` created an array of pointers to instances of A, and that therefore I could delete that instance of A. If that is incorrect, redoing the entire array, which is too complicated and expensive. As for using std::vector or some other container class, that would involve a huge amount of rewriting, so maybe next time. Probably best for me is to use the "move-down-and-ignore-the last entry" method.

Answer (score 0):

Objects allocated with `new` should be deleted with `delete`, and objects allocated with `new[]` should be deleted with `delete[]`. Any other permutation will cause undefined behavior, and also probably cause bad things to happen.

```
A * a = new A();
delete a;
A * b = new A[10];
delete[] b;
A * c = new A[50];
delete c; //UB!!!!
```

Comment: @EdHeal [Doesn't appear to be a compile error](https://ideone.com/rn2OAY).

Comment: @EdHeal Both are valid syntax. `new A()` will value-initialize the `A` object, and `new A` will default-initialize the `A` object. There's no difference if `A` is a class, but for example if `A` is a typedef for `int`, value-initialization sets the `int` to zero and default-initialization leaves the `int` indeterminate.